# Memory Leak issue when running dev environment on local machine [Vue/Nuxtjs]

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I have a Nuxt dev environment opened locally on my PC, which has 16gb of RAM, but something that keeps happening and has happened ever since I updated the framework on this specific site is that Volar (whatever that is) keeps hitting memory capacity and rebooting the server, even though nothing on my screen is rebooting--things just progressively lag more and more until it runs out of memory and flushes itself. This process repeats itself about 5-6 times before VSCode decides to terminate the process altogether. I have no idea what is causing this problem; my tsconfig.json seems to be excluding node-modules, and my other projects don't have this issue. It's a bit of an annoying problem, considering my site will be a catalog. For the time being though to the extent of my knowledge, nothing is connected serverside. I've only been using Nuxt for about a month now, so I'm still new to this whole thing.

Here is the output of the memory leak (simulated via simply running dev mode):

[image]

Also attached here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "lodash.pick": "3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "vite": "^5.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.1",
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^3.3.2",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^3.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^5.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "nuxt": "^3.9.3",
    "nuxt-vite": "^0.3.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.69.7"
  }
}
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```
// Generated by nuxi
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "vue",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": [],
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "~": [
        ".."
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "../*"
      ],
      "@": [
        "../../../../../../.."
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "../../../../../../../*"
      ],
      "~~": [
        ".."
      ],
      "~~/*": [
        "../*"
      ],
      "@@": [
        ".."
      ],
      "@@/*": [
        "../*"
      ],
      "assets": [
        "../assets"
      ],
      "assets/*": [
        "../assets/*"
      ],
      "public": [
        "../public"
      ],
      "public/*": [
        "../public/*"
      ],
      "#app": [
        "../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app"
      ],
      "#app/*": [
        "../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/*"
      ],
      "vue-demi": [
        "../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/compat/vue-demi"
      ],
      "#color-mode-options": [
        "./color-mode-options.mjs"
      ],
      "#vue-router": [
        "./vue-router-stub"
      ],
      "#imports": [
        "./imports"
      ],
      "#build": [
        "."
      ],
      "#build/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "#components": [
        "./components"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./nuxt.d.ts",
    "../**/*",
    "../node_modules/@nuxtjs/color-mode/runtime",
    "../node_modules/@nuxt/devtools/runtime",
    "../node_modules/@nuxt/telemetry/runtime",
    "..",
    "../../../../../../.."
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules",
    "../../node_modules",
    "../node_modules/nuxt/node_modules",
    "../node_modules/@nuxtjs/color-mode/runtime/server",
    "../node_modules/@nuxt/devtools/runtime/server",
    "../node_modules/@nuxt/telemetry/runtime/server",
    "../dist",
    "../.output"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Launch it through a terminal rather than VScode, might fix the issue since you will not be using Volar.